# In wordcloud(word, n, max.words = 100) :could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted

Tags: r

i have the following code and i have issue on the wordcloud

```
library(wordcloud)
tidy_books %>%
 anti_join(stop_words) %>%
 count(word) %>%
 with(wordcloud(word, n, max.words = 100))
```

i using the following link to work on the file   https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html
but i have a lot of error on the worldcloud

```
 In wordcloud(word, n, max.words = 100) :
  miss could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted.
```

how do i fix this?
thank you for your help

Comment: You are the one setting limits on the number of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(wordcloud)

tidy_books %>%
  anti_join(stop_words) %>%
  count(word) %>%
  {wordcloud(.$word, .$n, max.words = 100)}
```